# two binary trees return a boolean value

Tags: haskell

What is the meaning of the value which is returned by this function? you can use a diagram to explain if you want

```
data Tree a = Empty_Tree | Node {element :: a, left_tree,right_tree :: Tree a}
gurgle :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Bool
gurgle tree_a tree_b = case (tree_a, tree_b) of
      (Empty_Tree , Empty_Tree ) -> True
      (Empty_Tree , _ ) -> False
      (_ , Empty_Tree ) -> False
      (Node _ left_a right_a, Node _ left_b right_b) -> gurgle left_a right_b
                                                        && gurgle right_a left_b
```

Comment: Have you tried running this function on some trees and examining the output?

Comment: It is all about the shape (note that `element` is never matched on). However, I think there's more mirroring going on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's draw it. First I'll use a small circle for the empty tree and a circle for data at a node, with two branches for the subtrees. `left` and `right` will also themselves be trees.

[image: example simple trees]

OK, let's take the code line by line and unpack the case statement into pattern matching at the top level, because

```
function x y = case (x,y) of
    (0,1) -> this
    (1,10) -> that
```

can be written

```
function 0 1 = this
function 1 10 = that
```

## gurgle Empty_Tree Empty_Tree = True

[image: base case]

Noting much to learn here - it's yes if they're both empty. OK.

## gurgle Empty_Tree _ = False

This means we get stuff like

[image: empty,notempty gives False]

Because it gives `False` no matter what the second argument is. We've already eliminated the case that the second argument is `Empty_Tree` in the last line, so the second argument has to be non-empty to give False here.

The next line is very like it, only the other way round:

## gurgle _ Empty_Tree = False

Again, stuff like this

[image: nonempty, empty gives false]

is getting a No for an answer. I'm beginning to suspect once I've read these two lines it's checking that there's something the same with the shape of the two trees.

## Recursive case

### gurgle x y = gurgle (left_tree x) (right_tree y) && gurgle (right_tree x) (left_tree y)

This is the most interesting one. Notice the swap-sides thing it's doing. It's not just checking that the subtrees of both are the same, it's comparing right with left.

[image: not matched]

Also notice it's ignoring the value at the node - that's why I got rid of the numbers in this example.

## What do we need to make it True?

To make it true we need the shape on the left of one to match the shape of the right of the other:

[image: mirrored trees]

## What's your point?

The recursive case says the left of one must match the right of the other. The trees have to be mirror images of each other when you ignore the values.

## What's going on in the pattern match?

The recursive case in the original said

```
   (Node _ left_a right_a, Node _ left_b right_b) -> gurgle left_a right_b
                                                    && gurgle right_a left_b
```

Let's colour that code in to match the diagrams above:

[image: colour coded code]

Colouring it in is a good visual clue for what's going on, since the names `left_a` etc on the left don't mean anything special, they're just there to refer to bits of the tree.

Which bits?

[image: Node _ left_a right_a]

This is there to match up with the definition of Node:

[image: data Tree a = Empty_Tree | Node {element :: a, left_tree,right_tree :: Tree a}]

The first (grey) bit is the element. `element` is now a function from tree nodes to values.

The second (pale brown) bit is the left subtree, `left_tree`. It could be large and complex, or just an `Empty_Tree`. (It can be any Tree.)

The third (pale orange) bit is the right subtree, `right_tree`. They match up with my diagrams like this:

[image: a tree]

I've not put any details in the coloured box - it could be any tree, big or small.

When your original code put this on the left hand side

[image: colour coded code]

it was giving names to the subtrees, so that it could refer to them directly, rather than using the `left-tree` and `right_tree` functions.

Comment: @PeAcE Feel free to ask me to change the colours (as promised) or to explain something more clearly.

Comment: Thank you very much!! the general case (Say, (Node _ left_a right_a, Node _ left_b right_b) -> gurgle left_a right_b && gurgle right_a left_b) in binary tree is very confusing to me. Is there any rule or tip we can make it clearly, when dealing with the binary tree?

Comment: yes!! thanks a lot... everytime we are dealing with the pattern match in binary tree, the rules above are the good starting point right?

Comment: @PeAcE Yes, and you can do what you like on the right hand side of the `=`.

Comment: As an exercise, could you change it to check that the two trees have the same shape (not mirror image)? Could you change it to check they have the same shape and the same data in?

Comment: For example in `aboveTopValue (Node a _ _) = a+1`, the `a+1` is on the right hand side of the `=`.

Comment: for checking the same shape: changing the last line to, say,  (Node _ left_a right_a, Node _ left_b right_b) -> gurgle left_a left_b && gurgle right_a right_b)   ???

Comment: you are really a nice person!! Again, thanks a lot. While, may I have your email address and i can ask for your help through the email, if you are willing to.

Comment: @PeAcE When I want to be available for answering questions I log in to Stack Overflow. It really is the best way, because Stack Overflow is open 24 hours a day, and someone else may have a much better answer than me for some of your questions, and perhaps more importantly, a much sooner answer to your questions. (This happens a __lot__, and is one of the reasons I don't answer all the questions!) Also when I give good answers on Stack Overflow I get a number that increases and sometimes a pleasing green tick! :)

Comment: Also, if I help you here, other people can learn from my answers, so a larger number of peoplke understand stuf.